# Paste range to new sheet alphabetically by reference cell in range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to better organize a work list for my employees, based on customer information that they fill out.

So, I have a workbook with 3 sheets; the 'entry sheet' where I select what the customer has requested, a database sheet simply to make my selections easier, and a 'work list sheet' where I then export the selected information from the entry sheet. What I would love to do is when I click my export button have VBA take the range (which it already does) and paste it to 'Work List' BUT in alphabetical order ONLY by customer name (in this case F3 on 'Entry Sheet'. Basically, I don't want to sort the RANGE alphabetically- I only want to paste the range on the new sheet in alphabetical order referencing the F3. What am I missing?

Most of the 'solutions' I can find deal mostly with sorting the actual range itself, and I can't find anything in the PasteSpecial documentation that seems to help- although I admit I don't KNOW that I want it buried in the PasteSpecial- it just seems to make sense to me.

```
Private Sub exportInfo_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Entry Sheet")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Work List")

    If IsEmpty(Range("D3")) = True Then
        MsgBox "Customer Name Required", , "!!You Donut!!"
    Else
        copySheet.Range("F3:I8").Copy
        pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I going about this all wrong (completely possible)? Should I copy it as something else besides a range? Is there actually a function of PasteSpecial that will do this and I'm just missing it (again, completely possible)? I'd appreciate any pointers here. Thanks!

Comment: Don't follow. You want it in alphabetical order but without sorting?

Comment: Yeah- I knew this would end up being confusing. When I paste the whole range to the other sheet it is important that it stays together as a range. BUT there (on the new sheet) to have it listed alphabetically by customer last name is preferred. As my code is now it simply pastes the range in the next open line. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes I understand you want it alphabetically but I'm struggling with the idea of achieving this without sorting. Do you mean something else? You've either got to paste and then sort, sort before copying or paste somewhere intermediate, sort and then paste again.

Comment: I understand what you are saying- and I think it is exactly where I am getting stuck. I don't know how to sort entire 'blocks' (ie, the range) either once they are pasted OR before. I understand that I need to sort, certainly... I just don't know how to take that whole range, explain that I want to sort ONLY by last name, and then paste it in order BY that last name.

Comment: The best way is to record a macro of sorting to get the syntax and then adjust as appropriate. Once you have that nailed you can sort then copy or copy and then sort.

Comment: Oh, that makes some sense... let me dig into that a little. Thanks!

Comment: @suider To sort by `Last Name` only, set up a column (if you don't already have one) that contains only the last name.  Then sort the table by that column.